# javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi

I am using wildfly10.
This is my java code.

```
private Hashtable mEnv = new Hashtable();
InitialContext e = new InitialContext(mEnv);
```

The mEnv's value as flow.

```
mEnv = {
      java.naming.provider.url=localhost:8080,
       java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, 
      java.naming.security.authentication=simple,
      java.naming.security.principal=fc,
      java.naming.security.credentials=1234
```

}
When I run this command , I have such error.

```
javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.cppro.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from [Module "deployment.cppro.war:main" from Service Module Loader]]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from [Module "deployment.cppro.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.cppro.war:main" from Service Module Loader
null
null
```

Please help me.
thanks.

Comment: I've never used Wildfly before, but it seems like you're missing some jar file in your classpath. Have you added the necessary libraries before running it?

Comment: Hello sir.Thank you for message me.I don't know what are the jar file.

Comment: So what else have you tried to resolve this issue? It'd be easier for us to help you if you can include what actions have been done to fix the problem. If you don't know what is the jar file, at the very least you can google to find out which jar it is that contains the required class.

Comment: hello sir.Thank you for reply.I have tried too many. But I cannot do it.if you want, I can give you my teamviewer id and password.so you enter my computer.

Comment: It seems you're quite new to the community, so please allow me to inform you that that's not how it works here. It's very unlikely that you'll find any of us to do your work. So you have tried many? Describe to us (in summary) what you have tried and what the results are. Good questions will attract more people to help you. Anyway, like I said, I've never used Wildfly before. I hope you'll be able to resolve it. After resolving it, please answer your own question here and then mark it as resolved. Maybe there are others who encounter the same problem as this.

Comment: Look at the ejb-remote examples in the wildfly quickstarts for how to call. Jnp hasn't been used for many years

Comment: Thank you for reply.this is my skype id.arnoldbenda.Please contact me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JNP is the old naming protocol for JBoss AS5. You have to use the new JNDI properties for WildFly 10. Take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/JNDI+Reference (depending on why you need an InitialContext in the first place)

Comment: I am using java 1.8 and wildfly10.There is org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory class too.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are facing this problem and are using modules consider add modules related to jndi.dns or jndi.url to JAVA_OPTS at server startup

```
--add-exports jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=ALL-UNNAMED
```